# How to get the i'th random number directly in C++?

Tags: c++, random

Suppose I want to get directly the 100th random number generated by rand(), without generating the previous 99th random numbers.

let me rephrase. Is there such a random number generator, which can directly generate the i'th random number (given a seed), without iterating over the first (i-1)th generations? For example, suppose given a seed 100, a generator G can generate {1, 2, 5, 7, 3, 6, ...}. How can I get 6 without generating {1, 2, 5, 7, 3}?

Comment: What's the point since it's **random**? (although the randomness isn't that good).

Comment: It's a random number. Why would you want to do this? It'll be like choosing a 'random' random number.

Comment: In some cases, I want to reuse the i'th random number (which should be deterministic). But I don't want to store them.

Comment: You don't need to *store* the previous 99, just iterate 100 times and save the last value.

Comment: @Skyqe __should__ be. Don't rely on that, if you need to use seeds and deterministic behaviour, use something more suitable. But this is not a good question.

Comment: What is wrong with the first 99?

Comment: @Paul R My point is exactly to skip the 99 times' iteration and generate the 100'th number directly.

Comment: Yes, but why? It seems like an unusual thing to do because the 100th pseudo-random number isn't any more random, or objectively better, than the first, second or 99th.

Comment: Since you say you need to use a deterministic PRNG, then why not just generate the 100th random value once (using a test harness), and then store it as a constant in your actual program?

Comment: I don't quite understand the downvotes on this question...

Comment: @hyde before the edit, it was confusing. And it is definetely not a C++ question. It seems more an algorithm/PRNG question than a programming one.

Comment: Some RNG libraries (including mine) have a "discard" function that runs through loops of the RNG function without providing output; this still generates them, but is a bit faster. The only algorithm I know of with the particular mathematical property that you can generate the nth value directly is Blum Blum Shub.

Comment: @Lee Daniel Crocker noted. Will check it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Technically, it would depend on your random number source:

1. it's a genuinely random hardware device (it won't be), and your request is outright impossible.
2. it's a [pseudo-random number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator): the answer depends on the exact generator used.

   - if your PRNG has a period of exactly 100, you can just reuse the last value. Also, your PRNG is horrible
   - if you can genuinely compute `PRNG(100)` without requiring the results of `PRNG(99..0)`, you can reimplement it yourself. Also, your PRNG is still horrible
   - if your PRNG is not horrible, you're out of luck. You just need generate all the intermediate values and throw 99 away

Comment: I still don't get the OP's request/why they need this, but good explaination

Comment: I'm not sure about your point 2.  All of the PRNG that I know are based on something like `i[n] = f(i[n-1])` (for the `n`th random number).  If you know `f`, it should be possible to find an `f'` such that `i[n] = f'(n)`.  (It's possible, however, that `f'` is inordinately complicated.  And it certainly means knowing `f`, which in the case of `rand`, isn't specified.)

Comment: @James Kanze Hmm, this is a good point. But just as you said, i[n] = f'(n) is probably super complicated.

Comment: @Skyqe Probably.  I've never tried to work it out for the types of functions which are used in PRNG, but I suspect that if `f'` isn't super complicated, then it won't be a very good PRNG.

Comment: Yeah, neither 1 nor 2 are at all plausible, I was just exhausting the possibilities.

Comment: @JamesKanze I'm not too fresh on related math, but there are functions where you can not skip to Nth iteration even theoretically (I think). Consider for example calculating Mandelbrot fractal, you have to iterate each point until it "escapes" or iteration limit is reached. Pseudo random number generator should be able to use similar function.

Comment: @hyde I don't know myself.  I'm pretty sure that the most frequently used functions (linear congruent generators) for random numbers could be transformed, but I'm less sure about some of the later ones.  Or cryptographically secure ones.  But typically, `rand()` doesn't use anything that complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Not generally possible. Pseudo-random number generators have internal state, which changes when new number is generated. While you could have a generator where you could skip ahead several iterations in one go, the algorithm would have to be designed to make that possible. You could examine sources of some `rand()` implementation to see if it is possible. Though, I think that a random number generator where you could do this would not produce very high quality random numbers...

However, looking at your need, consider just taking a hash value of sufficient quality from iteration number. MD5 is probably fine if you are not doing crypto/security application. Combine a seed to the data you calculate hash from, if you need.

Comment: I asked this question because I read somewhere that four-wise independent binary random numbers can be generated directly given a seed and an index i.

Comment: @Skyqe I added a possible solution to the answer.

Comment: The Blum Blum Shub algorithm is an exception. It's slow, but it's very secure, and you can mathematically generate the billionth value directly if desired without iterating.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you want deterministic behaviour and are using C++

Use `std::mersenne_twister_engine`, which is a pseudo-random number generator, and can be easily instantiated with a seed.

Moreover, you have access to the function `discard`, which does exactly what you want.

Comment: still, ``discard`` has linear complexity. It seems that you are asking for constant time "advance" operation... but I don't know any robust PRNG which allows so.

Comment: So you have really understood my question. I just hope this linear complexity is fairly cheap.

Comment: If your program is heavily affected by the complexity of an random generator ``discard`` operation, then something is wrong with either your program or your setup. Although I can only speculate, as you haven't showed code or discussed your motivation. Nevertheless, your question (once understood) is valid.

Comment: I can explain my motivation to you. Indeed what I want to do is to sketch a set of intervals using random binary variables. Suppose the entire domain has length N, then the total number of variables is also N. To sketch an interval [a,b], I need to know the binary variables within this interval. A variable might be reused several times because the intervals may overlap with each other. Since I don't want to store these variables for large N, a generator which can directly generate the i'th variable is preferable.

Comment: For your next question: include the explanation on your original question, and add some code to show what you are trying to accomplish (and what you have tried). Everyone will be more friendly and will understand you better... and probably someone will come up with a clever approach that may be interesting.